# Solaris 10 as a DHCP Client

Tags: dhcp, solaris

Linux DHCP Server, many Linux clients.

One Solaris client.

Some of the machines have their MAC addresses within the dhcpd.conf on the DHCPD server, and they all pick up the appropriate IPs.

The Solaris machine though, grabs one from the pool instead. Ignoring its MAC->IP assignment. Why?

Also, where is the dhcp lease file within Solaris, so that I could clear it - just to make sure.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

DHCP lease delegation is done by the server, not by the client.  So either your reservation is wrong (typo, or server not restarted to pick up the reservation), or your client isn't using your server.

The only exception to this rule is if the client already has a lease.  Sometimes it will ask the server, "can I renew this existing lease?" and the server will say "yes, you can keep using it."  Most of the time though the server will say "no", forcing the client to begin the dhcp process from scratch, resulting in the reservation being issued.  (Sometimes when the server says "no", the client just hangs on to the lease until it expires before starting the dhcp process over again.)

If you set your dhcp server's syslog to pick up `*.debug`, dhcpd will drop all kinds of detail into your messages file and you can see exactly what it thinks is happening.

Google suggests you can release/renew your lease on the Solaris 10 system by doing this:

```
# ifconfig nge0 dhcp release
# ifconfig nge0 dhcp
```

... where `nge0` is whatever your ethernet device is.

Comment: Actually, it is more common to get the same IP address during the renew phase.  My home cable modem has had the same address for nearly 4 years now, and everything at work gets renewed unless we have run out of addresses.  ISC's DHCP server at least tries hard not to churn through, so clients usually just work.  Also, most clients start renewing at the 50% expiration mark, so churn is low.

Comment: thank you David. I realise that the delegation is done by the server, albeit there's normally a leases file on the client, which is responsible for tracking the lease expiration and the properties provided by the server. I'm trying to ascertain whether this exists on a Solaris machine, if so - where is it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-4554/dhcptm-1.html#scrolltoc) the Solaris 10 Admin Guide from Sun, with DHCP configuration details.